# Visual Studio 2015 Warnings not triggered

Tags: c#, visual-studio, compiler-warnings, roslyn

Just upgraded from VS-2012 to VS-2015. All my projects (CSharp libraries) are set to be compiled with a warning level of 4 (highest level possible). Back in VS-2012 in one of my projects I have two warnings of type

- CS0414 [The private field is assigned but its value is never used](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z62k595w.aspx) (Warning level 3)
- CS0649 [The private field is never assigned to and will always have its default value](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/03b5270t.aspx) (Warning level 4)

I expect this warnings to be triggered as these are the result of an internal refactoring, switching to a different third party component. To me, these warnings are crucial as they actually indicate ToDo's that have to be taken care of.

In VS-2015 however these warnings are not triggered and do not occur in the "Error list" view.

Yes, I could put actual ToDo comments there which will pop up then but I don't worry about the locations that I know of, but the locations that will be dead ends in future refactorings which will then potentially never been noticed due to VS not firing the warning.

As far as I can see from MSDN documentation above and configurable warning levels in VS, I cannot see any difference in the way I would have to configure VS or the projects themselves.

Is it possible, that the underlying "Roslyn" compiler is (currently?) not (yet?) able to detect these warnings based on its semantic analysis? Or am I missing something else?

**Edit**

To give some further information. I use rebuild solution in both 2012 and 2015. So a missing rebuild of the project cannot be the reason for not published warnings.

A third warning of type

- CS0618 [Member is obsolete](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x5ye6x1e.aspx) (Warning level 2)

is showing up in both, VS-2012 and VS-2015

**Edit 2**

Here is a small coding example (Just create a new project -> class library). One interesting finding is, when I first created the project, the warnings occurred in both, VS-2012 and VS-2015 - So I had a look into my current case to see where the differences are, and it turned out, that marking the class as being `abstract` yields the result of VS-2015 not issuing the warnings any more. When the class is not abstract, VS-2015 warns as VS-2012 did. But in my eyes, the case that it is abstract should not matter, as the fields are declared private anyway.

```
// When the class is being marked as abstract, VS-2015 will not issue any warning.
// When the class is not abstract the warnings are issued.
public abstract class Demonstrator
{
    // This should trigger warning CS0169 Warning Level 2
    private int _UnusedField;

    // This should trigger warning CS0414 Warning Level 4
    private int _AssignedButNotReadField;

    public Demonstrator()
    {
        _AssignedButNotReadField = 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Just to state the obvious, did you try a "Rebuild Solution"?

Comment: @PhillipNgan: Yes, I did trigger a rebuild ;-)

Comment: Is the warning tab enabled? (highlighted)

Comment: You mean in the ErrorList? Yes it is enabled there are two other warnings showing up but not those I mentioned above. Will edit the question accordingly.

Comment: There is a chance this is a change of behavior in Roslyn, could you provide short code code that can reproduce the issue?

Comment: @svick See updated question for code sample. As far as I can tell, to me, this seems to be a bug in the Roslyn compiler. I maybe should open an issue on the respective GitHub repo...

Comment: @Tobias Yeah, I think that opening an issue is the right approach here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out, that this behavior is actually to be considered a bug in the current version of Visual Studio 2015 Update 3. I opened an issue on that on the GitHub repository of Roslyn. For others experiencing the same issue, [here](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/13652) you can track the state of that issue.